# Could you please tell me how to use LaTeX to draw the following graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

Could you please tell me how to use LaTeX to draw the following image?

[image: Draw this image using LaTeX]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE.

This is a first approach, using `calc` Ti*k*Z library. It's helpful to place coordinates relative to others.

I'm not drawing the dashed lines. If you want them you also need to make a couple of `clips` (for example).

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{surface/.style={blue,left color=blue!30,fill opacity=0.8}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
                    x={(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)},y={(1cm,0cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}]
% coordinates
\def\myangle{70} % trial an error!
\coordinate (V)  at (0,0.5,2.5);
\coordinate (A1) at (-135:1);
\coordinate (A2) at (-\myangle:1);
\coordinate (A3) at ($(0,2)+(180-\myangle:1)$);
\coordinate (A4) at ($(0,2)+(45:1)$);
\foreach\i in {1,...,4}
  \coordinate (B\i) at ($(A\i)+(V)$);
% axes
\draw[-latex] (-2,-2,0) --++ (4,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (-2,-2,0) --++ (0,5,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (-2,-2,0) --++ (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
% surface
\draw[surface] (A1) arc (-135:-\myangle:1)  -- (B2) arc (-\myangle:-135:1)   -- cycle;
\draw[surface] (A2) arc (-\myangle:90:1)            arc (270:180-\myangle:1) -- (B3)
                    arc (180-\myangle:270:1)        arc (90:-\myangle:1)     -- cycle;
\draw[surface] (A4) arc (45:180-\myangle:1) -- (B3) arc (180-\myangle:45:1)  -- cycle;
% uncomment this to show some coordinates
%\foreach\i in {1,2,3,4}
%  \node at (A\i) {$A_\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An impressive answer that should not have been given. This is not a "do it for me" site  but a "I tried this but it didn't  work" site.